# 16-bit adder outputs wrong results for some numbers

Tags: vhdl

Here is the code I have written for a 16 bit adder - The results of this files should be compared with a adder written in functional format: A+B, so they should make sense. The files are uploaded [here](https://files.fm/u/qjd9byay):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Full_Adder_16 is
        Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
               b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
               s : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
    end Full_Adder_16;

    architecture Behavioral of Full_Adder_16 is

    component Full_Adder 
        port(x, y, cin: in std_logic;
        sum, cout: out std_logic);
    end component;

    type cinout is array (0 to 15) of std_logic;
    signal c : cinout;
    signal cout  : STD_LOGIC;

begin

    c(0) <= '0';
    adding: for i in 15 downto 0 generate
        leftmost: if i=15 generate 
            Full_Adder_15: Full_Adder port map (x => a(i), y => b(i), cin => c(i), sum => s(i), cout => cout);
        end generate;
        otherwise: if i/=15 generate 
            Full_Adder_x: Full_Adder port map (x => a(i), y => b(i), cin => c(i), sum => s(i), cout => c(i+1));
        end generate;
    end generate;

    end Behavioral;
```

And here is the testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity Full_Adder_16_tb is
end;

architecture bench of Full_Adder_16_tb is

  component Full_Adder_16
      Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
             b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
             s : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
  end component;

  signal a: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
  signal b: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
  signal s: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);

begin

  uut: Full_Adder_16 port map ( a => a,
                                b => b,
                                s => s );

  stimulus: process
begin

    -- Put initialisation code here
        A <= "0100010010110000";
    B <= "0001010111011110";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0011000011110111";
    B <= "0100000101000001";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0000000000000001";
    B <= "0010011000000111";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0011110010110011";
    B <= "1000111101011110";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0010000100100001";
    B <= "1111101000100111";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0001011100100011";
    B <= "0101101101101101";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "1011000110111001";
    B <= "1001011001011111";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0000001011001010";
    B <= "1000011011101011";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0011110110100000";
    B <= "1100111000000010";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0100000111111000";
    B <= "0001001111100101";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "1011111001111100";
    B <= "0100001101010111";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "1111000110000001";
    B <= "1010000100001110";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0111000111001011";
    B <= "1011000111010100";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "1011011101101010";
    B <= "1100111100101110";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "1111001001010111";
    B <= "0110010000100001";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0111111101101100";
    B <= "0111000100001111";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0000111101111000";
    B <= "1100011111101100";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0011100001100111";
    B <= "1010101100100000";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "1111111101000111";
    B <= "0110111101011100";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "0011111101000001";
    B <= "1100100001100100";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "1011011111000111";
    B <= "1000111101011011";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "1001011010010100";
    B <= "0110001100101111";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "1111111000100101";
    B <= "1111111110001010";

    wait for 10 ns;

    A <= "1011100101000001";
    B <= "0000100000000011";

    -- Put test bench stimulus code here

    wait;
  end process;


end;
```

I just need the sum value since the result will be an alu output. But the result is wrong for some numbers, here is the wave form:

[image]

I have used the same adder to write a code for a multiplier but it works fine. Any comments to solve this problem will be appreciated.

The Full_adder is as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Full_Adder is
    port(x, y, cin: in std_logic;
    sum, cout: out std_logic);
end Full_Adder;

architecture my_dataflow of Full_Adder is

begin

sum <= (x xor y) xor cin;
cout  <= (x and y) or (x and cin) or (y and cin);

end my_dataflow;
```

Comment: The fact that cinout has the opposite range direction to all your other vectors stinks, but may not be the problem. However it's clear that you *really* need to think about the direction of carry propagation in binary arithmetic. I also recommend you upgrade the testbench to assert the sum equals the expected value and report the errors explicitly. Nobody's going to try to read that waveform.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me a hint how to assert the errors explicitly?

Comment: The two additions that fail  8481 + 64039 = 5984 (Should be 72520) and 45497 + 38495 = 18456 (should be 83992) are both off by 2**16 (65536). You're seeing roll over on the adder output due to lack of enough bits for the particular operands and the results are correct for the hardware. (And yes someone read the waveform, although it would be easier on your audience to provide the incorrect additions in text). Note the results can't be duplicated without full_adder being included, it's not a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I just uploaded file and edited the question.

Comment: Your Mediafire files may disappear over time. Please include everything necessary to reproduce the problem in your question. There are actually 12 such roll overs in your testbench a and b values.

Comment: I changed the link and uploaded three files needed to check.

Comment: External links aren't guaranteed to be non-volatile. Stackoverflow is about questions and answers useful as a search resource to future readers, it's why there's [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) guidelines. If everything required is not included in the question a future reader might not be able to replicate the problem and any solution.

Comment: Please put all the relevant code in the question. Don't use external links.

Comment: Your shouldn't redefine a `std_logic_vector` for no clear reason, as you are doing with type `cinout`.

Comment: Sorry, I put all the three vhdl files required to run this code in my post.